# Issue with fragmentmanager.popbackstack();

Tags: android-fragments, back-stack

unable to solve the issue with Fragments back stack. When I try to pop, it throws errors :

> Could not find class
>   'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$1', referenced from
>   method android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setEpicenter
>   Could not find class
>   'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21$3', referenced from
>   method
>   android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransitionCompat21.setSharedElementEpicenter

and on backpressed again, it crashes.

My code :

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_place, fragment, fragmentTag);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Pop :

```
int stackCount = getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount();
if (stackCount > 0) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStackImmediate();
}
```

Comment: I am getting the exact same error, however the code continues to work. This should be a bug.

Comment: Filed issue https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=89244 for this.